# Query a manytomany relationship

Tags: django

I have two models in my app like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class Bar(models.Model):
    bar_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bar= models.ManyToManyField(Foo)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.bar_name
```

and there is a `Bar` pk (let's say 1)

How can I get all the related objects of `Foo` with `Bar` id 1 ?

Comment: First you get the `Bar` object, `Bar.objects.get(id=1)` and then you get all the `Foo` objects linked with this `Bar` object by `Bar.objects.get(id=1).bar.all()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the attribute name from `bar = models.ManyToManyField(Foo)` like this

```py
Bar.objects.get(id=1).bar.all()
```